# Check if a matrix is symmetric in Excel and LibreOffice

Tags: excel, matrix, libreoffice-calc

I'm searching for a solution to check if a matric is symmetric. I'm interested in both Excel and LibreOffice Calc. I don't want any VBA/Basic stuff, just regular formulas.

I've used both products to define a matrix using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> trick.

I've transposed the matrix, thinking it could help.

Now, I'm stuck. I don't know how to compare the original matrix and the transposed one. I'm sure it has to be a way with the **IF** formula, but can't find which.

Comment: Isn't there a operation which could work directly on arrays ? Without having to check one by one the coefficients ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Excel you can check if a matrix is equal to its transpose using `AND` as an array formula.

Example:

[image]

Note that my Excel is a German one. So `WAHR` = `TRUE`.

```
{=AND(A3:B4=TRANSPOSE(A3:B4))}
```

will lead to

```
AND({1,5;5,7}={1,5;5,7})
```

then  to

```
AND({TRUE,TRUE;TRUE,TRUE})
```

which leads to `TRUE`.